# Like I am / were a different person

Tags: verbs, subjunctives

> She looks at me like I **am** a different person.
>
> She looks at me like I **were** a different person.

I heard someone say the first sentence. It is an imaginary situation. What *mood* is appropriate here?  Should not this usage call for subjunctive?

Comment: The first sentence sounds natural to me, although I'd always contract *I am* to *I'm* in speech.  The second sentence sounds somewhat archaic.  I'd never say it, myself.

Comment: I wouldn't say either one, personally.  I'd use as if I were.  Also, to answer your question, I believe the usage calls for the subjunctive.  After all, you're not a different person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that sentence **is** in the subjunctive mood, so *were* is the correct verb.

The subjunctive mood is the verb form used to express a command, a wish, a suggestion or a condition that is contrary to fact.[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm) A verb is in the subjunctive mood when it expresses a condition which is doubtful or not factual, and is often found in a clause beginning with the word *if*, or in clauses following a verb that expresses a doubt, a wish, regret, request, demand, or proposal.[<sup>2</sup>](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000031.htm)

Your sentence certainly falls into that category; because the speaker is not another person.

As for the meaning of the sentence, I can think of at least two possible meanings:

> She looks at me like I were a different person.

could mean:

> She looks at me like she thinks I am somebody else. (perhaps I resemble an old friend of hers)

or:

> She looks at me as though she wants me to change. (maybe she's glaring at me, because we've already discussed my drinking problem, and here I am, getting hammered again)

The first interpretation is not factual (I can't be someone else), and the second one conveys a wish (that I would be someone else – in other words, that I would behave differently). Either interpretation would be in the subjunctive mood.

While I was looking for examples of the subjunctive mood, the closest sentence I found to your example was this one[<sup>3</sup>](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/subjuncterm05.htm):

> "In the night he awoke and held her tight as though she were all of life and it was being taken away from him." (Hemingway, *For Whom the Bell Tolls*)

As others have said, you've used the word *like*, which could be replaced with *as if* or *as though*. Just because the sentence uses *like* instead of *as if* doesn't make the sentence any less subjunctive.

<sup>NOTE: This is a rather advanced topic, and this question might have been better for ELU, but I've done my best to address it here.</sup>

Comment: Interestingly, Hemingway used _present subjunctive_ when talking about a past event. There is the _plueperfect subjunctive_ for this case: "as though she **had been** all of life...". Otherwise there is no difference between the subjunctive clauses while in different tenses: "I **am** holding her tight, as though _she were all of life_" v "I **was** holding her tight, as though _she were all of life_."

Answer (score 0):

I would replace 'like' with 'as if' in both sentences because the latter is more tranditional and therefore grammatical.

> 

```
She looks at me as if I am a different person.

She looks at me as if I were a different person.
```

> 

The first sentence implies that I am really a different person. 
The second one refers to an imaginary situation if I borrow your terminology.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The O.P. is apparently already aware of the possibility of using _if_.